# No internet on VM (server 2008) hosted by a machine with internet access

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

Not a network expert - I have VM with VM Workstation 8. The host machine has internet but I can't get internet on the VM.
Any hints?

Put the network setting of the machine on "`Bridged`" \ "`replicate physical network connection state`".

BTW - I managed to share folder inside the VM and access that from the hosted machine (maybe relevant...).

Answer (score 0):

In VM Hardware settings for Network Adapter check Custom:Specific virtual network and choose VMNet8(NAT) for example, press OK. Now on host system VMWare Network Adapter VMNet8 will appear in adapters list. You have to share internet access with this adapter. Guest systems ip address must be in the same subnet as VMNet8